# Javascript Show More Button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make the script when someone is pressing Show More to get the id of the button and if the id starts with "Show_More_ID_" to get the number of id and after to make the Box who class is "Box_Show_ID_" to show more or less

Example ID/Class:

```
<div class="Box_Show_ID_1"></div>
<input type="button" id="Show_More_ID_1" value="Show More" />
```

This is the code what i make for right now but is not working ...

http://jsfiddle.net/UPdmH/

Comment: what is `image_id` in your fiddle ?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't have a jQuery lib selected. Also, what is 'image_id'?

Comment: sorry image_id.split('_'); need to be Box_ID.split('_'); ... i get a script what im trying to convert for what i need ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/UPdmH/2/

essentially you were getting the id from the wrong index

`var Box_Data_ID        = ID_Split[3];`

Answer (score 1):

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UPdmH/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var Box_Data_MSG_1      = "Show More";
 var Box_Data_MSG_2      = "Show Less";
 var Box_Data_Height     = "117px";

 $("input[id*='Show_More_ID_']").click(function() {
  var Box_ID             = $(this).attr("id");
  var ID_Split           = Box_ID.split('_');
  var Box_Data_ID        = ID_Split[ID_Split.length-1];
  var Box                = ID_Split[2];

  var Button_Value       = $('#Show_More_ID_' + Box_Data_ID).attr("value");

  if(Button_Value == Box_Data_MSG_1) {
   $('#Show_More_ID_' + Box_Data_ID).attr('value', Box_Data_MSG_2);
  }

 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the JSFiddle doesn't really indicate what you want with the show more button, if it is a link, or if it is supposed to reveal another div

If you change the id to ShowMoreID_1 it would make it a bit easier:

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var val = $(this).attr('id');
  var str = val.split('_');
  if(str[0] == 'ShowMoreID') {
     var id = str[1];
    // do stuff
  } else {
    // dont do stuff
  }
});
```

Updated to include jQuery library.  I tweaked it to what I think you want to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZQ3pD/2/

Comment: i try your code but didnt work with what changes i make ... can you please check what can be the problem ... thanks http://jsfiddle.net/ZQ3pD/

Answer (score 0):

What about this Show more/less demo? DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/uEXvk/1/

```
var orgContent = $('.excerpt').html();
var txtContent = $('.excerpt').text().substr(0, 50) + '... <a id="morelink">more</a>';
$('.excerpt').html(txtContent);
$("body").on("click", '#morelink', function(){
    $('.excerpt').html(orgContent);
    $('<a id="lesslink"> less</a>').appendTo('.excerpt');
});
$("body").on("click", '#lesslink', function(){
    $('.excerpt').html(txtContent);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if there's more complexity than really needed. Look at this. I changed a bit of your HTML, added a jQuery library (you tagged it as JavaScript but are writing jQuery), and added an click() function:

http://jsfiddle.net/qTNzc/

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    this_id = $(this).attr('id'); 
    $('.Box_Show_ID_'+this_id).toggle();
 });
```